# Why useState causes re-execution of component with default value also

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am new to React native development. I want to understand how useState works.

```
import React from 'react'
import { View, Text } from 'react-native'
import Styles from './AdsStyle'
import { useContextSelector } from 'use-context-selector'
import { StateContext } from './State'
import { useState } from 'react'
import { useRef } from 'react'
import moment from 'moment'
import { useEffect } from 'react'
//To-do: Ads cx countdown timer.
const CountDownTimer = () => {
  const myState = useContextSelector(StateContext, (state) => state.myState)
  const timerRef = useRef(null)
  const [timer, setTime] = useState(myState == null ? 0: myState.endTime)

  if(myState === null){
    clearInterval(timerRef.current)
    return null
  }
  useEffect(()=>{
    updateTimer()
    return () => {
      clearTimeout(timerRef.current)
    } 
  })

  let remainingTime 
  const updateTimer = ()=>{
    timerRef.current = setInterval(()=>{
      remainingTime = timer - 1000
      if(remainingTime <0){
        clearInterval(timerRef.current)
        remainingTime = 0
      }
      setTime(remainingTime)
    },1000)
  }

  const renderCountDownTimer = () => {
    return (
      <View>
       <Text>{moment(timer).format('mm:ss')} </Text>
      </View>
    )}
    return renderCountDownTimer() 
}

export default React.memo(CountDownTimer, () => true)
```

I am simply building the count down timer. There are two issues i am facing for now.

1. When control comes to  `const [timer, setTime] = useState(myState == null ? 0: myState.endTime)` it simply goes to first line to re-execute the component again. Every thing works fine if i have hardcoded value in useState.
2. if i move the code `const [timer, setTime] = useState(myState == null ? 0: myState.endTime)` after the

   if(myState === null){
               clearInterval(timerRef.current)
               return null
             }

then react fails with an error that `Rendered more hooks than during the previous render`

Can someone pls explain both these cases.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You are not following the rules of hooks https://reactjs.org/warnings/invalid-hook-call-warning.html